# Average on the most recent date for which data is available

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table (on BigQuery) that looks like the following:

| Date | Type | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-04 | A | 5 |
| 2021-01-04 | A | 4 |
| 2021-01-04 | A | 5 |
| 2021-01-02 | A | 1 |
| 2021-01-02 | A | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 3 |
| 2021-01-04 | B | NULL |
| 2021-01-04 | B | NULL |
| 2021-01-02 | B | NULL |
| 2021-01-02 | B | NULL |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 5 |
| 2021-01-04 | C | NULL |
| 2021-01-04 | C | 4 |
| 2021-01-04 | C | NULL |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 3 |

What I would like to get is the average score for each type but the average should be taken only on the most recent date for which at least one score is available for the type. From the example above, the aim is to obtain the following table:

| Type | AVG Score |
| --- | --- |
| A | (5+4+5)/3 |
| B | (2+5)/2 |
| C | (4)/1 |

I need a solution that could be adapted if I want the average score, not for each type, but for each combination of two columns (type/color), still on the most recent date for which at least one score is available for the combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution is as given below, you can try it:-

```sql
SELECT type, AVG(score)
FROM mytable
WHERE score IS NOT NULL
  and (type, date1) in (
    SELECT (type, max(cast (date1 as date)))
    FROM mytable
    WHERE score IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY type
  )
GROUP BY type
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've edited the question to add another score column that is not NULL at the same time. Do you think we could adapt this solution for the case we have multiple score columns?

Comment: You need to add additional constraints 'Score2 IS NOT NULL' in sub query. It will work.

Comment: By adding the constraint `Score2 IS NOT NULL` in the same subquery, I think we will get the most recent date where both scores are available while we'd like to have the most recent date for each score separately. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks Vibhor! I've posted a new question to handle the case of multiple columns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66245500/average-on-most-recent-date-for-which-data-is-available-for-multiple-columns.

Comment: Hello, i have updated my solution for same. Hopefully it will work for you. All the best !!

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original question.

One method uses window functions:

```
select type, avg(score)
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by type order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where score is not null
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by type;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've edited the question to add another score column that is not NULL at the same time. Do you think we could adapt this solution for the case we have multiple score columns?

Comment: @Baskoa . . . This answers the question that was asked here.  Adding another column should be in a *new* question.

Comment: Sure thank you. Here is the new question to handle more columns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66245500/average-on-most-recent-date-for-which-data-is-available-for-multiple-columns. (I've rollbacked the current question to how it was when posted)