# Average on most recent date for which data is available for multiple columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table (on BigQuery) that looks like the following:

```
|    Date    |    Type    |    Score1   |    Score2   |
|------------|------------|-------------|-------------|
| 2021-01-04 |      A     |      5      |     NULL    |
| 2021-01-04 |      A     |      4      |     NULL    |
| 2021-01-04 |      A     |      5      |     NULL    |
| 2021-01-02 |      A     |      1      |     NULL    |
| 2021-01-02 |      A     |      1      |     NULL    |
| 2021-01-01 |      A     |      3      |      2      |
| 2021-01-04 |      B     |     NULL    |      3      |
| 2021-01-04 |      B     |     NULL    |     NULL    |
| 2021-01-02 |      B     |     NULL    |      4      |
| 2021-01-02 |      B     |     NULL    |      4      |
| 2021-01-01 |      B     |      2      |      5      |
| 2021-01-01 |      B     |      5      |      3      |
| 2021-01-04 |      C     |     NULL    |     NULL    |
| 2021-01-04 |      C     |      4      |     NULL    |
| 2021-01-04 |      C     |     NULL    |     NULL    |
| 2021-01-01 |      C     |      1      |      5      |
| 2021-01-01 |      C     |      2      |      4      |
| 2021-01-01 |      C     |      3      |      4      |
```

What I would like to get is the average score for each type but the average should be taken only on the most recent date for which at least one score is available for the type. From the example above, the aim is to obtain the following table in one query (that can contain subqueries):

```
|    Type    |  AVG Score1 |  AVG Score2 |
|------------|-------------|-------------|
|      A     |  (5+4+5)/3  |    (2)/1    |
|      B     |   (2+5)/2   |    (3)/1    |
|      C     |    (4)/1    |  (5+4+4)/3  |
```

I need a solution that could be adapted if I want the average score, not for each type, but for each combination of two columns (type/color), still on the most recent date for which at least one score is available for the combination. It should be also possible to adapt it if I have more score columns and for different aggregations (AVG/MAX/MIN...).

N.B.: A first question was asked to handle the same problem with only one score column: [Average on the most recent date for which data is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238476/average-on-the-most-recent-date-for-which-data-is-available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the same approach, but you need to enumerate each column separately -- so filtering doesn't work.  That would be:

```
select type,
       avg(case when seqnum_1 = 1 then score1 end) as avg_1,
       avg(case when seqnum_2 = 1 then score1 end) as avg_2
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by type, score1 is null order by date desc) as seqnum_1,
             dense_rank() over (partition by type, score2 is null order by date desc) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by type;
```

Note:  This includes the `NULL` values in the averages.  There is no harm in that, because they don't affect the results.  You could also express this as:

```
select type,
       avg(case when seqnum_1 = 1 then score1 end) as avg_1,
       avg(case when seqnum_2 = 1 then score1 end) as avg_2
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by type order by score1 is not null desc, date desc) as seqnum_1,
             dense_rank() over (partition by type order by score2 is not null desc, date desc) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by type;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to solve above mentioned problem is given below :-

```sql
SELECT
  type,
  AVG(score),
  AVG(score2)
FROM (
  SELECT
    type,
    (CASE
        WHEN score IS NOT NULL AND (type, date1) IN ( SELECT (type, MAX(CAST (date1 AS date))) FROM mytable WHERE score IS NOT NULL GROUP BY type ) THEN score
      ELSE
      NULL
    END
      ) AS score,
    (CASE
        WHEN score2 IS NOT NULL AND (type, date1) IN ( SELECT (type, MAX(CAST (date1 AS date))) FROM mytable WHERE score2 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY type ) THEN score2
      ELSE
      NULL
    END
      ) AS score2
  FROM
    mytable)
GROUP BY
  type
```

Hopefully it will work for your.

Output will be as expected :-

[image]